# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - How can I avoid it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, error-handling

I have an asynchronous upload process. After it finishes, it pokes the main thread to update the UI.

```
    @try {
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(updateUploadFinished)]) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUploadFinished) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to perform selector on main thread: %@",[exception reason]);
        return;
    }
```

The problem is if I move away from this view I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I've tried to avoid it, as you can see in the code above, but it still crashes the app. How can I get around this?

Comment: 1) `The problem is if I move away from this view` what do you mena with move away 2) Show us the crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to remove the delegation of that asynchronous call on your viewWillDisappear.